# Why does this method still give rounding errors on currency?

Tags: c, math, floating-point, rounding-error

This is the code:

```
float accountBalance = 0; //global

//this function gets called many times  
int Accumulate(float amount) //amount in currency form, i.e. xxx.yy
{
   float fixroundVal = 0;

   amount = amount * 100; //change to full number (removes decimals)

   accountBalance += amount;

   fixroundVal = accountBalance / 100;

   printf("fixroundVal=%f",fixroundVal);//really gets stored   

}
```

So before, I didn't have the fixroundVal value and scaling by 100 - it was just `accountBalance += amount;`

I was getting really bad rounding errors, so I did the local scaling by 100 each iteration and **it got rid of a lot of rounding errors** but once and a while, I am still getting a few.

I tried increasing the 100 scale by other multiple of 10 and I actually got more rounding errors.

I can only use C, no libraries.

How can I fix this?

(more respect for bank software;)

Comment: You should be doing this math in `decimal` form, using some library like http://www.bytereef.org/mpdecimal/

Comment: do you have some inputs/outputs to show ?

Comment: @robert-harvey: I can only use C, no libraries., updated question...

Comment: @karim: it's really difficult to post meaningful data...but it is definetly a rounding error, it is only off by 1 cent. Should this method work in general?

Comment: No, this method doesn't work.  However, if you round to the nearest int in each iteration, it may come closer to working.  It is better if you represent everything as an integer number of cents, whether you use floating-point numbers or not.

Comment: @tmyklebu: how/where do I use int's with this? accountBalance as int does not seem to work?

Comment: @GregMcNulty: `rint()` after multiplying by 100.  Note also that printing with `%d` interprets your `float` as an `int`.

Comment: @tmyklebu: the printf was not used, but changed it to %f. ok let me try rint()

Comment: Using `int` is _not_ the solution given its small guaranteed minimum range (-32767 to 32767) .  But using _integer_ math _is_ a solution good approach.  Determine the minimum currency unit (e.g 1 cent) and store all number as that, in `long long` or `double` (recommend `double`) - (maybe consider `long` or `float`).  After _any_ operation that may not provide exact results like "7% of a pre-tax total", round the value: `double tax = rint(total * 0.07);`.  There are a number of additional issues too, but this to get you started.

Comment: suprise, suprise, banks have this partial penny problem all the time.  They get around it by 1) rounding down for customer earned interest (interest bearing checking for instance) and 2) rounding up for bank earned interest (morgage interest for instance)).

Answer (score 7):

This is because when you divide the result by 100 you are still doing floating point division and storing the result in floating point representation. Floating point numbers can only ever be approximated by using fractions in binary. You have to come up with the closest sum of 1/2 1/4 1/8 etc to the actual real value. Some numbers for example 0.2 can't be represented precisely in floating point.

The solution is to represent dollar amounts as the number of cents as an integer throughout the system. Then you can represent something like 20 cents exactly.

Comment: Also: To print out a currency value stored in cents, you can avoid converting to float by doing something like this (provided you know the amount is positive):  `printf("%d.02d", amount / 100, amount % 100);`

Comment: @mclaassen: at first, the input comes in as a string, i.e "45.78" - I currently use float x = atof(amount); ----if I do int x = atoi(amount), will i loose the decimal? what is the best way to get the string into decimal cents?

Comment: @mclaassen This is not a good idea for the same reason that the floating-point division by 100 in the question is not a good idea.

Comment: @GregMcNulty There might be a better way but you could split the input into the parts before and after the period and then do atoi on each and just use 100 * dollars + cents to get the cents amount as an int.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying issue is the use of `float`, which is a binary floating point number (usually).

Many multiples of 0.01 can't be represented exactly in a binary floating point
number such as `float`, for example, 0.10. So when you write 0.10 and assign it to a `float`,
what you get is not exactly the same value as 0.1, but is a value slightly more than 0.1.
Adding two `float`s doesn't solve the problem either, since the exact values of the 
floats are added, not their approximations. For example, 0.1 as a float, plus 0.1 as another
float, would result in a number slightly more than 0.2, and not exactly 0.2.

Comment: You'll get the closest `float` to `0.2` if you add `0.1` to `0.1`.  Think about why.

Answer (score 0):

```
given that you want to round up if fraction is >= .05 and otherwise, round down

int Accumulate(float amount) //amount in currency form, i.e. xxx.yy
{
    float fValue = (amount * 100.0) + .5;

    int   iValue = floor(amount); // rounds down to nearest decimal value

    printf("fValue=%f",fValue);//really gets stored   

    return( iValue ); // return rounded value (*100) to caller
}
```